# Error initializing firebsae auth in Golang

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-authentication, jwt

I'm new to Go and I'm trying to implement functionality to check Firebase jwt tokens, inspired by this code:

https://github.com/MousyBusiness/AppEngineAPI/blob/master/app.yaml

My main.go

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "package.com/components"
    "package.com/config"
)

type Response struct {
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

func main() {
    client, err := config.InitAuth()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("failed to init firebase auth 2", err)
    }

    r := gin.Default()

    versioned := r.Group("/v1")
    // Use JWT auth middleware
    versioned.Use(config.AuthJWT(client))

    // Create entry
    versioned.POST("/", func(c *gin.Context) {

        log.Println("created task")

    })

    //Try with calling methods instead of inline functions in main.go
    versioned.GET("/test", components.GetWorkouts)   //tested, OK

    // Start the app
    // start API
    errRun := r.Run()
    if errRun != nil {
        log.Fatalln("failed to run Gin app")
    }
}
```

My fbauth.go

```
package config

import (
    "context"
    "os"

    firebase "firebase.google.com/go"
    "firebase.google.com/go/auth"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

var (
    firebaseConfigFile = os.Getenv("FIREBASE_CONFIG_FILE")
)

func InitAuth() (*auth.Client, error) {
    opt := option.WithCredentialsFile(firebaseConfigFile)
    app, err := firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), nil, opt)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "error initializing firebase auth (create firebase app)")
    }

    client, errAuth := app.Auth(context.Background())
    if errAuth != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(errAuth, "error initializing firebase auth (creating client)")
    }

    return client, nil
}
```

And my middelware.go

```
package config

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "firebase.google.com/go/auth"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

    //Import secrets package
    "package.com/config/secrets"
)

const (
    authorizationHeader = "Authorization"
    apiKeyHeader        = "X-API-Key"
    cronExecutedHeader  = "X-Appengine-Cron"
    valName             = "FIREBASE_ID_TOKEN"
)

// Gin middleware for JWT auth
func AuthJWT(client *auth.Client) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        startTime := time.Now()

        authHeader := c.Request.Header.Get(authorizationHeader)
        log.Println("authHeader", authHeader)
        token := strings.Replace(authHeader, "Bearer ", "", 1)
        idToken, err := client.VerifyIDToken(c, token) // usually hits a local cache
        if err != nil {
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{
                "code":    http.StatusUnauthorized,
                "message": http.StatusText(http.StatusUnauthorized),
            })
            return
        }

        log.Println("Auth time:", time.Since(startTime))

        c.Set(valName, idToken)
        c.Next()
    }
}

// API key auth middleware
func AuthAPIKey(secretId string) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        key := c.Request.Header.Get(apiKeyHeader)

        secret, err := secrets.GetSecret(secretId)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("failed to get secret")
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{
                "code":    http.StatusUnauthorized,
                "message": http.StatusText(http.StatusUnauthorized),
            })
            return
        }

        log.Println("comparing secret with provided key", secret, key)

        if secret != key {
            log.Println("key doesnt match!")
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{
                "code":    http.StatusUnauthorized,
                "message": http.StatusText(http.StatusUnauthorized),
            })
            return
        }

        log.Println("no error during check")
        c.Next()
    }
}

// AppEngine cron authentication
func AuthAppEngineCron() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        cron := c.Request.Header.Get(cronExecutedHeader)

        if cron != "true" {
            log.Println("not invoked by cron - access denied")
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{
                "code":    http.StatusUnauthorized,
                "message": http.StatusText(http.StatusUnauthorized),
            })
            return
        }

        c.Next()
    }
}
```

In my .env file I have the following (modified):

```
FIREBASE_CONFIG_FILE="./firebase.json"
API_KEY_NAME="AIzaXXXXXXXXXX"
```

And my firebase.json file (modified)

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": mobile-test",
  "private_key_id": "4870XXXXXXXXX",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEGYE=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-yqf07@mobile.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "11590XXXXXX",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-yqf07%40wodhero-mobile.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}
```

When running the app I get:

> failed to init firebase auth 2 error initializing firebase auth
> (creating client): google: could not find default credentials. See
> https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc for
> more information

Comment: Try printing `firebaseConfigFile` and make sure that `option.WithCredentialsFile()` can read it